# How to prevent inline bloc from my email to stack on iPad?

Tags: html-email, responsive, email-client

I originally created an email using MJML and adapted the code to improve the mobile version.

1) I haven't any problem while checking the email with chrome and testing it with all desktop client with litmus, but the ipad version of the email stack inline blocks.

2) Some elements only displayed on mobile using media queries are not visible when testing the email whereas I can see them with chrome.

Here is the preview of the issues: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGq96.jpg)

Here is the link of the html file: 
[Html file](http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/email-universcience.html)

Here is the beginning of the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
  <title>Invitiation à l'avant-première "Quoi de neuf au moyen âge ?"</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <style type="text/css">
    @media (max-width:660px) {
      @-ms-viewport { width: 320px; }
      @viewport { width: 320px; }
    }  
  </style>
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a { padding: 0; }
    .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass * { line-height: 100%; }
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
    table, td { border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
    img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
    p { display: block; margin: 13px 0; }
    .hidden-desktop {display: none!important; max-height: 0; font-size: 0; overflow: hidden; line-height: 0; mso-hide: all;}
  
    @media (min-width:660px) {
      .mj-column-per-100, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-per-100"] { width: 100%!important; }
      .mj-column-px-200, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-200"] { width: 200px!important; }
      .mj-column-px-30, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-30"] { width: 30px!important; }
      .mj-column-px-430, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-430"] { width: 430px!important; }
      .mj-column-px-410, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-410"] { width: 410px!important; }
      .mj-column-px-20, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-20"] { width: 20px!important; }
    }       
    @media (max-width:659px) {
      .mj-column-per-100, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-per-100"] { width: 280px!important; display: block!important; margin: 0 auto; }
      .mj-column-px-200, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-200"] { width: 280px!important; display: block!important; margin: 0 auto; }
      .mj-column-px-30, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-30"] { width: 0px!important; }
      .mj-column-px-430, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-430"] { width: 280px!important; display: block!important; margin: 0 auto; }
      .mj-column-px-410, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-410"] { width: 280px!important; display: block!important; margin: 0 auto; }
      .mj-column-px-20, * [aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-20"] { width: 0px!important; }   
      .invitation-desktop { display: none!important; }  
      .image-expo { height: 400px!important; background-repeat: no-repeat!important; }
      .hidden-desktop{ display: block!important; max-height: none!important; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.5!important; overflow: visible!important; }
      .mobile-space{ height: 20px; }
      .mobile-auto-height{ height: auto!important; }
      .hidden-mobile{ display: none!important }
      .logo-table { width: 80px!important; float: left; }
      .logo-padding { padding: 7px!important; }
      .logo { width:66px!important;height:66px!important; }
      .invitation-mobile-title{ width: 200px; float: left; height: 80px;}
      .social-mobile{ width: 80px!important; height: 80px; display: inline-block!important; }
      .social-space-mobile { width: 20px!important; }      
    }     
  </style>  


  <!--[if mso]>
  <xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  </xml>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if !mso]><!-->  
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--<![endif]-->
 

</head>

<body style="background: #e8e8e8;">
  <div style="background-color:#e8e8e8;">

  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="660" align="center" style="width:660px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
      <![endif]-->

        <div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:660px;">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">

                <!--[if mso | IE]>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;width:660px;">
                    <![endif]-->

                      <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-per-100" class="mj-column-per-100" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:15px;" align="center">
                                <div style="cursor:auto;color:#a6a6a6;font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:300;line-height:13px;text-transform:none;">
                                  Vous avez des problèmes d’affichage ?
                                  <a href="#" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 11px; text-transform: none; font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif; color:#a6a6a6">
                                    Visualiser cet email en ligne
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>

                      <!--[if mso | IE]>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="660" align="center" style="width:660px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
      <![endif]-->

        <div style="margin:0 auto;max-width:660px;">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">

                  <!--[if mso | IE]>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="vertical-align:top;width:200px;">
                      <![endif]-->

                        <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-200" class="mj-column-px-200" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:200px;">
                          <table class="logo-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:top;background:#fff;" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="logo-padding" style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:25px;" align="center">
                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="width:150px;">
                                          <img class="logo" alt="" title="" height="150px" src="http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/logo-cite.png" style="border:none;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:150px;" width="150">
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>

                          <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                          <table class="hidden-desktop invitation-mobile-title" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200px" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td width="20px">
                                </td>
                                <td width="180px">
                                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:11px 0px;background-color:#d81921;" align="center">
                                          <div style="cursor:auto;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:28px;font-weight:400;line-height:28px;text-transform:uppercase;">Invitation</div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                       <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px;background-color:#000" align="center">
                                          <div style="cursor:auto;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;line-height:30px;text-transform:uppercase;">
                                            <span style="letter-spacing: 3px">
                                              avant-première
                                            </span>
                                          </div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                          <!--<![endif]-->                          
                        </div>
                         



                      <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      </td>
                      <td style="vertical-align:top;width:30px;">
                      <![endif]-->

                        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
                        <div class="mobile-space hidden-desktop" style="font-size:1px;line-height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <!--<![endif]--> 

                        <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-30" class="mj-column-px-30" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:30px;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>

                      <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      </td>
                      <td style="vertical-align:top;width:430px;">
                      <![endif]-->

                        <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-430" class="mj-column-px-430" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:430px;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="left">
                                  <div class="image-expo" style="margin:0 auto;height:200px;max-width:430px;background:#f2b3b7 url(http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/bg-expo.jpg) bottom right / 430px 200px no-repeat;">

                                    <!--[if mso | IE]>
                                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:430px;">
                                    <v:fill origin="0.5, 0" position="0.5,0" type="tile" src="http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/bg-expo.jpg" />
                                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
                                    <![endif]-->

                                    <table class="image-expo" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="200px" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;height:200px;background:#f2b3b7 url(http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/bg-expo.jpg) bottom right / 430px 200px no-repeat;" align="center" border="0" background="http://bank.digital-expression.fr/universcience/bg-expo.jpg">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">

                                          <!--[if mso | IE]>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="vertical-align:top;width:410px;">
                                                <![endif]-->

                                                  <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-410" class="mj-column-px-410" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                            <div style="font-size:1px;line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;" align="left">
                                                            <div style="cursor:auto;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;font-size:30px;font-weight:700;line-height:30px;text-transform:uppercase;">
                                                              Quoi de neuf<br> au moyen âge ?
                                                            </div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                            <div style="font-size:1px;line-height:20px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;" align="left">
                                                            <div style="cursor:auto;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:16px;text-transform:uppercase;">
                                                              TOUT CE QUE L’ARCHEOLOGIE<br> NOUS RÉVÈLE
                                                            </div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
                                                            <div style="font-size:1px;line-height:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td style="word-break:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;" align="left">
                                                            <div style="cursor:auto;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;font-size:40px;font-weight:700;line-height:40px;text-transform:uppercase;">
                                                              <a href="#" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 0px">+</a>
                                                            </div>
                                                          </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </div>

                                                <!--[if mso | IE]>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20px;">
                                                <![endif]-->

                                                  <div aria-labelledby="mj-column-px-20" class="mj-column-px-20" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%" border="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                  </div>

                                                <!--[if mso | IE]>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <![endif]-->

                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  
                                    <!--[if mso | IE]>
                                    </v:textbox>
                                    </v:rect>
                                    <![endif]-->
                                  
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      
                      <!--[if mso | IE]>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <![endif]-->

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        
      <!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->
      
  <!--[if mso | IE]>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="660" align="center" style="width:660px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
      <![endif]-->

        <div class="mobile-space" style="font-size:1px;line-height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <![endif]-->



  ...I can't put the complete code on my post to be under 30000 signs.

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping,

Comment: Please share your code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's a common issue with iOs 9 and blank space between div. Even if font-size is set to 0px it acts like if it still here.
You'll have to minify your HTML to make it look nice again.

I did it for you : http://pastebin.com/0RX92bat and here's how it looks on Litmus on iPad Retina with Mail https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8jo5.jpg

You can use https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier to get the same result with these options :

```
{ collapseWhitespace: true,
  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
  minifyCSS: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem many times and the easiest fix I've found is to add a `margin: 0 -2px;` to each `display: inline-block;`:

```
`<div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 -2px;">`
```

The same problem exists on the web, as outlined in [Fight the Space Between Inline-Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) on CSS Tricks. This article includes a few other examples in case you don't like the negative margin hack.